# How to link Main menu items to feed-items? drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

Drupal 7.x, I use Feeds and Feeds News modules to import and display RSS feeds. 
Every feed linked to the main menu item, for example: `node/1484`. But when click on the main menu item, this open "View" tab, which is just empty, as feed items are on "View items" tab: `node/1484/feed-items`
How to link Main menu item to the feed items in "View items" tab, to show feed items directly?
What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: goto content->menus->main-menu and change the link?

Comment: you mean `structure/menu/manage/main-menu`. Yes, this is manual way. Is there way to set feed-item as default path for feed by changing appropriate settings?